# What is the technology behind firefox extensions?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, language

I want to create an extension that can manipulate or look at cookies in the browser.
Also, I want to be able to parse every page you visit and replace some URLs.

So here is the question: What is the language? Does it have the reach I need? Will it work smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox extensions are created using a mix of [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL) (XML User Interface Language) and Javascript.

You'll find plenty of explanation on the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions).